# About changing incorrect tags in suggested edits

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing, suggested-edits, retagging

Very often when I see a edited question made by another person, I see that the editor didn't change the wrong tag, for example, it's very typical that questions about high school algebra are tagged with linear algebra or abstract algebra. Other times I see that the editor hasn't added a correct tag, for example questions about Diophantine equations are only tagged with elementary-number-theory.

So, when I want to change the wrong tag(s) or add another tag(s)  I find that I can't because it's not possible to just change tags without making any corrections on the question itself.

Since I think that it's very important that questions are correctly tagged, my question is: is there a way to change or add just only tags?

Comment: Re: *It's not possible to just change tags without making any corrections on the question itself.* Are you sure about this? Looking at recent suggested edits I have found this one: [review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/723269), [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2038226/revisions).

Comment: Also related meta.SE post: [Has edit functionality changed? I cannot edit just tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285645) From that question is seems that it is bug which occasionally occurs, but typically you should be able to edit only the tags.

Comment: BTW I have changed the title of your post (since "About incorrect tags" is rather non-descriptive) and added ([meta-tag:suggested-edits]) and ([meta-tag:retagging]) tags - since this seems to be actually what you are asking about. Of course, if I somehow misinterpreted your question, go ahead and edit it again. (And I'd also like to say that any effort to help getting question correctly tagged is appreciated.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak don't worry about having changed the title. It's definitely more descriptive now.

Comment: Well, it seems that it's just a bug. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related meta.SE post: [Has edit functionality changed? I cannot edit just tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285645/has-edit-functionality-changed-i-cannot-edit-just-tags)

Based on that post it seems that it is an occasional bug (the cause is not identified in the linked thread), but usually the suggested edit which only changes tags should be possible. Indeed, there can be found several recent suggested edits, here are a few random examples:
[review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/723269), [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2038226/revisions); [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/723409), [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2038477/revisions); [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/131557/revisions), [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/131557/revisions); [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/723247), [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2038145/revisions).

So it should work in most cases. I guess you will be able to check that experimentally. (EDIT: It seems that you did and it worked [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/723607), [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2038947/revisions).)

Even if you can't edit the post, you can leave a comment suggesting how the tag should be changed. Either the OP or some other user with [edit privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) might see your comment and edit the tags. [The same advice](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25205/how-we-can-edit-the-posts-in-which-the-edit-we-suggest-is-less-than-6-characters) - using comments - applies if you cannot make edit suggestion because of [6 characters limit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length). And in the case of retags, possible alternative would be mentioning this in [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740). (Especially if you are not entirely sure how the tags should be changed.)